# How to disable asp.net membership redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-membership

ASP.NET membership by default redirects user to a login page, however I like to handle login from everypage using ajax form that I already implemented.

How can I have membership enabled on my website and also able to access all pages in my website without being redirected to login page.

**I'm using C# on visual studio 2010**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Darin pointed me to a blog that has the correct answer but it is too complex.

I found an easier method to achieve what I needed. I modifed web.config fie to add a few allowed folders and files. here is how:

All my Ajax responses are in a single folder like

```
/ajax/form1.ajax.aspx
/ajax/form2.ajax.aspx
/ajax/form3.ajax.aspx
```

So I can modify `web.config` and following rules to it

in `system.web` section I added

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

this will forbid unauthenticated users from accessing the website
and in `configuration` section I add

```
<location path="default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="ajax">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

this will allow unauthenticated users to access defaut.aspx and ajax folder.
obviously the login form also will be available to users if it is set in  `system.web` -> `authentication`

remember to remove the web.config file located in account folder that is overriding the access to folders and files.